# Using a value from initState() in a Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

So, am trying to load the result of getCoinData() method into a Text Widget.
This is my code from the CoinData class..

```
const apiKey = 'CF2BC5CD-FCC1-444C-9306-1363C005C4D2';

 class CoinData {

  Future<dynamic> getCoinData(String currency) async {
    String selectedCurrency = currency;
    http.Response reply = await http.get('https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/BTC/$selectedCurrency?apikey=$apiKey');
    var data = await jsonDecode(reply.body)['rate'];


    return data;

}
```

I tried calling getData method when the screen loads up, which actually worked when i tried printing coinData in the initState function.

```
class PriceScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _PriceScreenState createState() => _PriceScreenState();
}

class _PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  
  CoinData getData = CoinData() ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getData.getCoinData('USD').then((dynamic value)  {
      String coinData = value.toString();
    } );

  }
```

So, where am currently having a diffulty is on how to display my result coinData in the Text Widget

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(' Coin Ticker'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(

                  '1 BTC =  USD',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an asynchronous call that determines something in your layout, you'll have to rebuild your layout at least once after the call is completed (unless you're prefetching the data somehow, which is a whole other mess). In your case, you can have your Text widget hold some placeholder text like "Fetching data" until the call is done, then you can setState the value into the Text widget. How? Just use a variable in the Text Widget. Here's what your resultant code will look like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PriceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PriceScreenState createState() => _PriceScreenState();
}

class _PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  CoinData getData = CoinData();
  String coinData = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getData.getCoinData('USD').then((dynamic value) {
      setState(() {
        coinData = value.toString();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(' Coin Ticker'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            (coinData == "") ? "Fetching value..." : '1 BTC = $coinData USD',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't trigger a rebuild.  You need a FutureBuilder or equivalent to watch the future and trigger widget rebuild on change.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Not necessarily. With the way Flutter works at the moment, async calls are scheduled after synchronous work, so initState and the initial layout will complete before getCoinData starts. After that, calling a setState will rebuild the layout. This code works, however, I agree with you that a FutureBuilder would be a better, more sensible approach to this.